# Python - How to make sure that a line being read from a file contain only a given string and nothing else

Tags: python, file

In order to make sure I start and stop reading a text file exactly where I want to, I am providing 'start1'<->'end1', 'start2'<->'end2' as tags in between the text file and providing that to my python script. In my script I read it as:

```
start_end = ['start1','end1']
line_num = []
        with open(file_path) as fp1:
            for num, line in enumerate(fp1, 1):
                for i in start_end:
                    if i in line:
                        line_num.append(num)
        fp1.close()
        print '\nLine number: ', line_num
        fp2 = open(file_path)
        for k, line2 in enumerate(fp2): 
            for x in range(line_num[0], line_num[1] - 1):
                if k == x:
                    header.append(line2)
        fp2.close()
```

This works well until I reach start10 <-> end10 and further. Eg. it checks if I have "start2" in the line and also reads the text that has "start21" and similarly for end tag as well. so providing "start1, end1" as input also reads "start10, end10". If I replace the line:

```
if i in line:
```

with

```
if i == line:
```

it throws an error.

How can I make sure that the script reads the line that contains ONLY "start1" and not "start10"?

Comment: I'm not sure what error it raises (something downstream? You should share the traceback). But the problem is that the `line` still contains the newline at the end. Try `if i == line[:1]:`

Comment: If you want to recognise a particular pattern in a string, look into *"regular expressions"*.

Comment: Do the `'start1'`, `'end1'`, etc. markers always occur by themselves in a line?

Comment: Because if they do, you can simply replace `start_end = ['start1','end1']` with `start_end = ['start1\n','end1\n']` and be done.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. I think using regex is also a very elegant solution. But since the 'start1' and 'end1' were in one line all by themselves, adding a '\n' to them as suggested by @TigerhawkT3 solved the problem easily in this particular case. Thank you for all your answers.

Comment: Great; I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your markers are always at the end of the line, change:

```
start_end = ['start1','end1']
```

to:

```
start_end = ['start1\n','end1\n']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
prog = re.compile('start1$')
if prog.match(line):
   print line
```

That should return None if there is no match and return a [regex match object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.match) if the line matches the compiled regex. The '$' at the end of the regex says that's the end of the line, so 'start1' works but 'start10' doesn't.

or another way..

```
def test(line):
   import re
   prog = re.compile('start1$')
   return prog.match(line) != None
> test('start1')
True
> test('start10')
False
```

Comment: Why regular expressions? How does this differ from simply `line == 'start1'`, other than being overkill?

Comment: I'm all for simple. If line == 'start1' works for the asker, go for it. But that comment about the newline at the end, and the other comments about regex, prompted me to write up an example using regex.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look into regular expressions. The Python re library has some good regex tools. It would let you define a string to compare your line to and it has the ability to check for start and end of lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you can control the input file, consider adding an underscore (or any non-number character) to the end of each tag.

'start1_'<->'end1_'

'start10_'<->'end10_'

The regular expression solution presented in other answers is more elegant, but requires using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `find()`:

```
for num, line in enumerate(fp1, 1):
    for i in start_end:
        if i in line:
            # make sure the next char isn't '0'
            if line[line.find(i)+len(i)] != '0':
                line_num.append(num)
```