# Using a text file to save status in Python to avoid losing when close script

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to use a text file to save a flag to use in a script to avoid loos it when I close the script. The text file just content a letter or number that I write depending of situations in my script. I want to open the file and read the word/number on it ant use in a if-else sentence. I test this code but does not run correctly:

```
with open('errorflag.txt', 'r') as f:
first_line = f.readline()
print first_line
if first_line== "N":
    print " no errors detected"
else:
    print " error detected"
```

in the text file is only the word N and the result is allways the else option, Can someone helpme to find the good script, Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to make sure that a line being read from a file contain only a given string and nothing else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29951885/python-how-to-make-sure-that-a-line-being-read-from-a-file-contain-only-a-give)

Answer (score 0):

first I would suggest to use first_line[0] or is "N" in first_line, this is because end of line \n can be in said string. I would still use try/except to catch the error message.

Comment: Sorry stupid of me, the text file content was the word N and a space... I notice when I made a len()...Thanks anyway for your help and fast reply, I learn allways a lot with your comments.